# SystemError: <built-in function imread> returned NULL without setting an error

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, file-upload

I don't know what the problem in this code. I am just trying to read the user input image to imread.

Code:

```
    root = tk.Tk()
    #root.withdraw()
    root.geometry('600x400')
    def file():
        file = askopenfile(mode ='rb', filetypes =[('JPG File', '*.jpg'),('PNG File','*.png')])
        if file is not None:
            content = file.read()
            print(content)


open = tk.Button(root, text ="Open Image",command= lambda : file())
open.pack()


pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

img = cv2.imread(file, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
img = cv2.resize(img, (600, 400))
```

Error:-

```
 img = cv2.imread(file, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

SystemError: <built-in function imread> returned NULL without setting an error
```

Comment: Try printing the value of `file` before `imread` and debug. Probably the path given is incorrect.

Comment: <function file at 0x00000253A5BFC268> it showing this now with same error

Comment: Maybe a corrupt JPEG? Can you read it with another tool?

Comment: Also, weird errors like this could indicate that the system is in an unstable state, rebooting might help...

Comment: No, the JPEG is not corrupt and I have also tried rebooting the system but it won't work